# Does ibm jdk7 include JavaDB similar to Sun/Oracle jdk?

Tags: java-7, javadb

The Sun JDK 7 or 6 - both include the JavaDB database as part of the jdk. Does anyone know if the IBM jdk 7 ships with any such database or we can just use Apache Derby?
thanks.